# Deleting a list item <li> with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to delete a li item using jquery, but its not working. Here's my code:

the html file:

```
<li>
    <a href="nano.com/$username"><img class="avatar" src="images/$picture" width="48" height="48" alt="avatar" /></a>
    <div class="tweetTxt">
        <strong><a href="nano.com/$username">$username</a></strong> $auto
        <div class="date">$rel</div>
        $reply_info
        <div class="date"></div>
        <a class ="delbutton"  href="#" id = $id> Delete </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

The jquery file:

```
$(function () {
    $(".delbutton").click(function () {
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: info,
                success: function () {}
            });

            $(this).parents(".record").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
            }, "fast")
                .animate({
                    opacity: "hide"
                }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

the delete.php file:

```
<?php
    include("includes/connect.php");
    if($_POST['id'])
    {
        $id=$_POST['id'];

        $sql = "delete from {$prefix}notes where id='$id'";
        mysql_query( $sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: what part is not working? also, you're not sanitizing or escaping the $_POST['id'] which is used in your SQL statement and is thus susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: thanks @toxlk i was going add the escape after, its not in producion yet, i wanted to see if the delete would work, because when i click the delete link nothing happens! im still a newbie so i cnt find find out where the error is!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code...

- `element.attr("id")` references undeclared `element` but this should probably be `$(this).attr("id")`
- The `<li>` block has no class ".record" either
- **EDIT**: You only fade your `<li>` but do not actually remove it from the DOM (don't know if this was deliberate though)
- The `<a>`'s ID is not quoted (and not escaped either... as are the other strings you insert in PHP **(EDIT)** and the ID you use in your delete script - this is very dangerous as it allows cross-site scripting / XSS and SQL injection as [TokIk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242641/toxik) already pointed out)

PHP:

```
echo '<li class="record">
    <a href="nano.com/'.htmlentities($username).'"><img class="avatar" src="images/'.htmlentities($picture).'" width="48" height="48" alt="avatar" /></a>
    <div class="tweetTxt">
    <strong><a href="nano.com/'.htmlentities($username).'">'.htmlentities($username).'</a></strong> '.htmlentities($auto).'
    <div class="date">'.htmlentities($rel).'</div>'.htmlentities($reply_info).'<div class="date"></div> <a class="delbutton" href="#" id="'.htmlentities($id).'"> Delete </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delbutton").click(function(){
        var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: info,
                success: function(){
                            alert('success');
                },
                error: function(){
                            alert('error');
                }
            });

            $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
            .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

**EDIT**: Delete script (note the additional error check that `$_POST['id']` exists and the pseudo-function for quoting the ID):

```
<?php
    include("includes/connect.php");
    if( isset($_POST['id']) ) {
        $id  = quote($_POST['id']);
        $sql = "delete from {$prefix}notes where id='$id'";
        mysql_query( $sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your first point is incorrect, as $(function()  == $(document.ready()).

Comment: thank you GENIUS! can i just ask you know when i delete something it shows me a pop up with success! i dnt really want that

Comment: I inserted the `alert('success')` and `alert('error')` statements to show those popups so that you can verify that it actually gets to those points. Just remove these to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element in your HTML with a class of `record`. I would try something like this:

```
<li class="record">
    <!-- a bunch of other stuff -->
    <a class="delbutton" href="#">Delete</a>
</li>
```

then in the JS:

```
$(function ()
{
    $(".delbutton").click(function ()
    {
        if (confirm("..."))
        {
            $.ajax({ /* ... */});
            $(this).closest(".record").fadeOut();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but you know the delbutton .click function, isnt that meant to be before the irrelvant ajax stuff lol

Comment: You're right, haha sorry about that. Added it back in, plus return false.

Answer (score 1):

If your div look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>One | <a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></li>
    <li>Two | <a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></li>
    <li>Three | <a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></li>
    <li>Four | <a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.delete').live('click', function(event) {        
        $(this).parent().fadeOut()
    });
});​
```

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/9ekyP/

---

**EDIT:**

You can remove your `li` after getting response in `success` function something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.delbutton').live('click', function(event) { 

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "delete.php",
           data: info,
           success: function(){
              $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
           }
        });

    });
});​
```

Comment: thanks @naveed, i love your idea, but where can i put the ajax post stuff! sorry for disturbing you (one upvote for you)

Comment: You should only have one unique id per HTML page. Change the list's id to class and change jquery's id selector to a class selector.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `'.records'` is the container.

You can pass through your ID value to make `<li>` unique, result being:

```
<li id='record_12'>
//CONTENT
</li>
<li id='record_13'>
//CONTENT
</li>
```

And change your SUCCESS script to the following:

```
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var info = 'id=' + del_id;
if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
data: info,
success: function(){

     //Getting the unique LI and fading it out
      $('#record_' + del_id).fadeOut();

}
});
```

Comment: I guess it's not necessary to use IDs for the `<li>` because he's using `this.parents(".record")`.

Comment: True, I gave him the option coz I assumed his parent container is .records. He is tracing back to the parent and then targeting the relevant LI. (So he doesn't have to change his HTML code)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine well.I was trying to code a form that has multiple textbox, then after each textbox threre will be link called add which POST call the  other php called addnew.php.

In addnew.php data will we added to database(postgres). But I am geting problem while getting the post variable itself.

this is my code for form (I will chage for multiple textbox once it works fine)

```
script:
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('.add').live('click', function(event) {

            var da = $('form#myform').serialize();
            alert(da);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addnew.php",
                data:da,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data === "ok") {
                        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }

            });
        });

    });
});
```

Form

```
<form name='myform' id='myform'>
 <input name='da' type='text' id='da' value='none'>
 <a href='#' class='add'>Add</a>
</form>
```

addnew.php code here

```
<? php
 if( isset($_POST['da']) ) 
 {
       echo (da);
  }
?>
```